# c# razor actionresult parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm totally new at mvc razor, so please excuse my unfamilarity with this subject. If I understood well, it is the controller which gets the url parameter, like the following:

```
  // Get: /User/23
  public ActionResult(int? id) { 
       return View("User", id);
  }
```

So basically, this `ActionResult` gets the parameter in the url and sends it somewhere. But where?

Also, say I have a repository in which I return all the users in an `IQueryable<>` class. If the id is not null it gets only the relevant result, if not, it gets the whole list. Therefore, I'd like to return a list to the view and show the results. How can I do that? To ease the understanding I give the following example:

```
// I want to populate this list based on the id in the actionresult
@foreach(var u in MyList) { 
   name: @u.Name <br>
   lastname: @u.LastName <hr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return View` invokes a helper method in the base class, `Controller`.

It will return a `ViewResult`, with the parameter being the model passed to the view.

So if you want to pass through a list of User's, you would do this:

```
public ActionResult Users()
{
   var users = _repository.FindAllUsers();
   return View(users);
}
```

Note how i left out the View name, so the default convention will be to look for a View based on the action name, in this case `Users.cshtml`. Always try and use **convention over configuration** - this is what makes MVC great.

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApp.Models.User>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

**Shared\DisplayTemplates\User.cshtml**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
```

Note how i didn't use a `foreach` loop - i use i custom display template, again - convention over configuration.

Comment: wow, Thanks! But still, how can I pass an url parameter to the Model? Will ViewBag.Variable do the work or is there a better approach?

Comment: @Shaokan - what's the purpose of this URL? Is this to generate a link somewhere? If so, you should use a `Html.ActionLink` or a custom HTML helper. Let me know what type of URL you want to generate and i'll clarify.

Comment: @RPM1984 Okay, first of all let me state that I use this code only to train my coding skills, therefore, firstly, I'm not wondering about security. Anyways, I want to create a page which I can use like an sql database. I want to select table names from a list of links and then I want to populate a dynamic table based on the table I've selected. I cannot use a webgrid because I want to display each cell in a textbox so I can easily edit, delete or insert new data. In other words, I want to create a basic database interface. And I'm passing the variable table name from the url.

Comment: I've already done something similar, but I've done this using classic asp.net controls and c#, not using mvc razor :) So basically, I'm trying to learn with difficult things, I mean, difficult to me.

Comment: But how many different pages is this? From what i read, the first page will list all of the different tables as links. Then the second page will show table data based on the link that was clicked. Is that right? If so, there should be two action methods. One to return the list of table names, and the view will create `Html.ActionLink` for each table. Then those links will point to a second action method which displays the data from that table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually, that's only a page. Initially, I display a default table.

Comment: @Shaokan - they need to be 2 different action methods, since they serve two different URL's, and serve different content. Unless you want AJAX-style functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I guess I have still lots of reading to do

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return as the second parameter is the model passed into the view. You could then inherit the razor page in WebViewPage, or better, use the @model keyword. The data passed in is available within the page via the "Model" variable.

Good example of usage after that is at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have another question: How I can pass that variable to MyModel.cs?

Comment: @Shaokan Not sure what you mean by "pass that variable to MyModel.cs"